# MySQL query order by SUM field of another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have 3 table :

> hotel : id, hotel_name
>
> hotel_supplier:id, supplier_name
>
> hotel_price:id, hotel_id, supplier_id, allotment, price

I want to select all from hotel order by sum(allotment) of hotel price descending, so the result sort from hotel that have the most allotment. How to do this ..?, any ideas gratefully received..., thank.

> sorry, i am forget one thing, there is another condition, on hotel_price if price == 0 then allotment of the row is not count in sum(allotment).

Comment: clearify your question and provide some data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this variant:

```
select h.id, h.hotel_name, sum(hp.allotment)
  from hotel h join hotel_price hp on (h.id = hp.hotel_id)
 group by h.id, h.hotel_name
 order by 3 desc;
```

Comment: thank you for the quick respons, and it's work, but there is another condition, that I forget to write on my question at first time.

Comment: @ChadTimen If you mean you don't want to see hotels with sum = 0, then you should simply add condition `where hp.price <> 0` to the query.

Comment: it's not condition to get hotel result, but condition to get sum(allotment), example hotel A have 2 price from hotel_supplier, first is 100 with allotment 5, and second price is 0 with allotment 4, so the right sum(allotment) is 5 not 9, because price 0 is not count.
sorry if my explanation is too complicated.

Comment: @ChadTimen Your explanation is clear. If you add the condition I mentioned in the previous comment, you should get the result you need.